# Finding eigenvalue and eigenvectors of a matrix containing an imaginary number

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How do you solve for the eigenvalues given the matrix?  \begin{bmatrix}
        i & -2 \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}

I know how to get the characteristic polynomial $Ca(X)$; $X^2 - iX + 2 = 0$
But when I use the quadratic formula, I get something along the lines of 
 $[ i  +/- i(2\sqrt(2) ) ] / 2$ 
Wolfram and solution says eigenvalues are $X_1 = 2i$ and $X_2 = -i$

Comment: Now the next step is, how to find a set of eigenvectors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you left off,

$$X = \frac{i \pm \sqrt{(-i)^{2}-4(2)}}{2} = \frac{i\pm\sqrt{-1-8}}{2} = \frac{i\pm \sqrt{-9}}{2} = \frac{i\pm i\sqrt{9}}{2} = \frac{i\pm 3i}{2} = 2i, -i$$